# Difficulties in working with If statement in PHP multiple form validation

Tags: php

I have been trying to Validate an HTML form with PHP which of course has worked successfully. Th problem then i'm kinda having problems on where to add include file which contain a successful message after all validation is made.
Here is my code:

```
<?php
        $status=$codeErr="";
        if (isset($_GET['check'])) {
            $number=$_GET['number'];
            $code=$_GET['code'];

            if($number!=""){
                if(preg_match("/[0-9]/",$number) and strlen($number)=="11"){
                    $four=substr($number, 0,4);
                    if($four!="0706" and $four!="0813" and $four!="0803" and $four!="0806" and $four!="0703" and $four!="0816" and $four!="0810" and $four!="0814" and $four!="0903"){
                    $status='<p class="status">Number Entered is not an MTN Number</p>';
                    }
                }
                else{
                    $status='<p class="status">Invalid Number Format</p>';
                }
            }
            else{
                    $status='<p class="status">Please Enter an MTN Number</p>';
                }
            if($code!=""){
                if($code!=="324"){
                    $codeErr='<p class="status">Winning Code Not Recognized</p>';
                }
            }
            else{

                $codeErr='<p class="status">Please Enter Your Winning Code</p>';

            }


        }
```

This include file displays the form if not set.

```
        else if(!isset($_GET['check'])){

            include('includes/check.php');

        }
    ?>
```

Now i have another include file which contains a message to be displayed if all conditions are met while the check form goes off. Where do i include it?

Comment: I think, it's better you go through this link once [Validation](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_validation.asp). This explains a lot in simple ways. No need to be confused.

Answer (score 0):

You should use exceptions:

```
try {

    if (!$somethingOne) {
        throw new Exception('Something wrong one!');
    }
    if (!$somethingTwo) {
        throw new Exception('Something wrong two!');
    }
    if (!$somethingMore) {
        throw new Exception('Something wrong more!');
    }

    // success here only
    echo 'All right!';

} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getCode() . '<p>' . $e->getMessage() . '</p>';
}
```